# Trying to fix a NumPy asscalar deprecation issue

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, deprecation-warning

While trying to update an old Python script I ran into the following error:

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'. Did you mean: 'isscalar'?
```

Specifically:

```
def calibrate(x, y, z):
  # H = numpy.array([x, y, z, -y**2, -z**2, numpy.ones([len(x), 1])])
  H = numpy.array([x, y, z, -y**2, -z**2, numpy.ones([len(x)])])
  H = numpy.transpose(H)
  w = x**2
  
  (X, residues, rank, shape) = linalg.lstsq(H, w)
  
  OSx = X[0] / 2
  OSy = X[1] / (2 * X[3])
  OSz = X[2] / (2 * X[4])
  
  A = X[5] + OSx**2 + X[3] * OSy**2 + X[4] * OSz**2
  B = A / X[3]
  C = A / X[4]
  
  SCx = numpy.sqrt(A)
  SCy = numpy.sqrt(B)
  SCz = numpy.sqrt(C)
  
  # type conversion from numpy.float64 to standard python floats
  offsets = [OSx, OSy, OSz]
  scale = [SCx, SCy, SCz]
  
  offsets = map(numpy.asscalar, offsets)
  scale = map(numpy.asscalar, scale)
  
  return (offsets, scale)
```

I found that `asscalar` has been deprecated since NumPy 1.16. I found one reference that said to use `numpy.ndarray.item`, but I have no clue how to do that.

I did try this:

```
offsets = map.item(offsets)
scale = map.item( scale)
```

but got this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'map' has no attribute 'item'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) makes it quite clear how you need to call it. If you recognize that `map(fun, iterable)` effectively calls the function `fun` on each element of `iterable`, it's a small jump to figuring out how to call `np.ndarray.item` on each element of your `offsets` and `scale` list.

Comment: Note that if `OSx`, `OSy`, and `OSz` are all indeed one-element arrays, you could instead do `offsets = np.array([OSx, OSy, OSz]).squeeze()`

Comment: this use of `map` looks like python 2 usage. I'd use  `offsets = [OSx.item(), OSy.item(), OSz.item()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `numpy.scalar` using `numpy.ndarray.item`, that is, change

```
offsets = map(numpy.asscalar, offsets)
scale = map(numpy.asscalar, scale)
```

to

```
offsets = map(numpy.ndarray.item, offsets)
scale = map(numpy.ndarray.item, scale)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was one of the other things I tried and received this message

`
TypeError: descriptor 'item' for 'numpy.ndarray' objects doesn't apply to a 'numpy.float64' object
`

Comment: Use a list comprehension to apply the `item` method to each item of the list.  `map` requires a lambda: `list(map(lambda i: i.item(), offsets))`

Answer (score 6):

Temporary fix, worked in my case

```
import numpy

def patch_asscalar(a):
    return a.item()

setattr(numpy, "asscalar", patch_asscalar)
```

Comment: This is a supremely useful answer when the offending call is in a third party library that hasn't been updated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `X` is a 1d array with shape (6,), I created a dummy sample, and applied your calculations (thorough the first offsets)

```
X = np.array([1, 2.3, 3.2, .4,5.2, 3])
```

and got two lists of numpy scalars.

```
In [58]: offsets
Out[58]: [0.5, 2.8749999999999996, 0.3076923076923077]
In [59]: type(offsets[0])
Out[59]: numpy.float64
```

Looks like the `map` lines are Python 2, intended to produce lists of regular python floats.  Python 3 would use `list(map(...))`.

`item` is a method of numpy scalars (and single item arrays).  It could be used as:

```
In [60]: [OSx.item(), OSy.item(), OSz.item()]
Out[60]: [0.5, 2.8749999999999996, 0.3076923076923077]
In [61]: [i.item() for i in offsets]
Out[61]: [0.5, 2.8749999999999996, 0.3076923076923077]
```

One applies it to the OS values before they are collected in a list, the other uses a list comprehension (which is easier to use than `map`, at least for this).

Same for `scale`.

But for `scale` we don't need to take the sqrt individually; just make an array from the 3 values, apply sqrt to the whole array.  Then use `tolist()` method to create a list of python floats.  That's better than trying to do sqrt and item individually.

```
In [63]: np.sqrt(np.array([A,B,C]))
Out[63]: array([2.65491199, 4.19778444, 1.16425593])
In [64]: np.sqrt(np.array([A,B,C])).tolist()
Out[64]: [2.6549119933262744, 4.197784443104389, 1.1642559271506094]
```

Comment: Thanks this response is really useful for a follow on issue that I have.  Didn't realize that np.ndarry.item solved one issue but a similar issue exists for another map() function that is used to convert floats to ints.